# MySQL is inserting my favicon src into a table. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my PHP Code:

```
$con = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
if (!$con) die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $con);

if(isset($_GET['lost'])&&$_GET['lost']=='lost'&&isset($_GET['name'])){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO Losers (Name, Date) VALUES('$_GET[name]',NOW())");
}
mysql_close($con);
```

What is happening is that for each time someone submits the form, MySQL is inserting three records: their name, an image src within a canvas script, and the src of my favicon.

Why in the world would this happen?

### UPDATE

I've changed the $_GET variable to an unchanging string: 'Ben'.  Now it just puts 'Ben' in three times.  Why is it performing the sql function three times?

### SOLVED

My .htaccess file was redirecting all images to index.php.  I was trying to make SEO friendly URLs but I needed to fix the relative src values in my images.

Comment: Is this the only applicable code? I'm just as surprised (perhaps baffled is more appropriate) as you are that the query you listed here would insert that data...

Comment: Put the snippet you posted in a separate file, and set your form to post it to that file. Does the problem still occur then?

Comment: are you using `requre` or `include` directives to this code ? Maybe it's included and runs a few times

Comment: Put an `exit;` after the `mysql_query()` and see if the line is only inserted once. If it is, you have a multiple call problem. If it's still inserted many times ... well, `TRIGGER`s? Custom override of `mysql_query`?

Comment: Is this file called via AJAX or a standard submit?

Comment: @Naltharial exit made sure it was only inserted once.  How do I solve a multiple call problem?  Is the page auto-refreshing twice or something?

Comment: @bozdoz Can you post the entire page's code? It's possible you may be redirecting the page and forgot to kill the script, or calling in a page twice, or something that is not shown here.

Comment: @Duniyadnd I just started writing the page.  I don't think it would be useful.  Except, there is an embedded youtube video.  Perhaps that is doing something to the page.

Comment: Not pertinent to the question itself, but you don't sanitize the `$_GET['name']`, which means that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @kitsune Just started writing the page.  Thanks for the heads up though. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are probably redirecting all requests to your php file. It's triggered once for the actual request, your browser asks for favicon automatically and the 3rd is either css, js or something.

If you use apache, check your htaccess file.

Comment: I think you are absolutely correct.  That would make sense, since it is inserting src values. I must have written my .htaccess file incorrectly, forwarding all requests to index.php and it is interpretting the images as variables.  Thanks for your clairvoyance! :)